# How can I find all ruby gems installed with sudo gem install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sudo

I'm learning to code on ruby and before knowing any better I installed some  gems with `sudo gem install name-of-gem`, which is now wreaking havoc with some projects. I've read the gem documentation and have not found a way to show which gems have been installed with `sudo`. How can I do find them?

Comment: `sudo gem list`, of course

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If I compare `sudo gem list` to `gem list` I see a lot of gems that appear on both lists. Does your command list both gems installed with and without sudo? How would you revert the mess? Please include it as an answer so I can assign it to you. Thanks!

Comment: do `which gem` and `sudo which gem` point to the same binary?

Comment: Nope. I guess this means there are two installs of some of the gems, one with sudo and another one without, with the same version numbers. Should I just make a giant sudo gem uninstall with all the gems to uninstall and them do a giant gem install with all the gems so they are back in the system? Should I just sudo gem uninstall all and then work only with bundle on a per project basis?

Comment: Yep, in this case, it's safe to nuke all gems from `sudo gem list` (well, almost all. There are a few system gems, like `bigdecimal`, which I'm not even sure you can uninstall) and use bundler from then on.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SergioTulentsev. Can you please write it what you just said in the comments as an answer so that I can mark your answer as valid or do you prefer that I edit my answer and give you credit there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system comes with a built-in ruby, it (and the gems) are in protected folder. To install gems, you need `sudo`.

Normally, though, you leave the system ruby alone and install newer version with one of the ruby version switchers (RVM, chruby/ruby-install, rbenv/ruby-build). But before you discovered version switchers, you may have installed some gems with `sudo` into the system ruby.

If `which gem` and `sudo which gem` return different paths (which likely means that under `sudo` you use system ruby and not your custom one), you can safely uninstall all of the gems you installed with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at your history on the computer to find the commands you used:

```
history | grep "sudo gem"
```

And then do `sudo gem uninstall name-of-gem` to remove them.

Credit goes to [Jad Joubran](https://github.com/jadjoubran).

Comment: This solution is 1) OS-dependent; 2) shell-dependent; 3) requires history to be enabled and not scrambled/edited over time and 4) uses a hammer to turn the screws.

Comment: @mudasobwa How would you solve it taking care of all your caveats?

Comment: As @SergioTulentsev specified in the comments: `sudo gem list`.